# XML node reading

Tags: xml, vb.net

I have an xml file as seen in the below;

```
<ZPPORDER01>
  <IDOC BEGIN="1">
    <EDI_DC40 SEGMENT="1">
      <TABNAM>EDI_DC40</TABNAM>
      <MANDT>100</MANDT>
      <DOCNUM>0000000000000001</DOCNUM>
    </EDI_DC40>
    <Z1PPORDITEM SEGMENT="1">
      <AUFNR>000000000123</AUFNR>
      <POSNR>0001</POSNR>
      <Z1PPORDOPER SEGMENT="1">
        <VORNR>0010</VORNR>
        <ARBPL>PIGME</ARBPL>
        <Z1PPORDCOMP SEGMENT="1">
          <POSNR>0100</POSNR>
          <CPARAM>RV ;</CPARAM>
        </Z1PPORDCOMP>
        <Z1PPORDCOMP SEGMENT="1">
          <POSNR>0200</POSNR>
          <CPARAM>PLT;</CPARAM>
        </Z1PPORDCOMP>
     </Z1PPORDOPER>
    </Z1PPORDITEM>
  </IDOC>
</ZPPORDER01>
```

I would like to read PosNR and CPARAM for each `<Z1PPORDCOMP SEGMENT="1">` node. As seen there are multiple nodes with the same node name(Z1PPORDCOMP SEGMENT="1" and same child names(POSNR,CPARAM).

I would like to read all child's inner text and assign to 4 different strings in a scan.

I wrote a script...I have defined 4 strings to read the data for each child. I can read the value from first two, but I don't know how to get data from the next child values.

I have searched Xml.XPath is used but I couldn't figure out how to use it in this case.

```
dim doc as System.Xml.XmlDocument;
dim node as System.Xml.XmlNode;
doc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument;
doc.Load("\\mypc\ShareOn\INPUT\Test.xml");

dim PosNR0100 as string ;
dim PosNR0100_CPARAM as string ;
dim PosNR0200 as string ;
dimPosNR0200_CPARAM as string ;

PosNR0100       = doc.SelectSingleNode("/ZPPORDER01/IDOC [@BEGIN='1']/Z1PPORDITEM [@SEGMENT='1']/Z1PPORDOPER [@SEGMENT='1']/Z1PPORDCOMP [@SEGMENT='1']/POSNR").InnerText;

PosNR0100_CPARAM    = doc.SelectSingleNode("/ZPPORDER01/IDOC [@BEGIN='1']/Z1PPORDITEM [@SEGMENT='1']/Z1PPORDOPER [@SEGMENT='1']/Z1PPORDCOMP [@SEGMENT='1']/CPARAM").InnerText;
PosNR0200       = ?
PosNR0200_CPARAM    = ?
```

Comment: Have you considered using an XML library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use xpath queries like this:

```
Imports System.Xml

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim src = "C:\temp\ZPPORDER.xml"
        Dim doc As New XmlDocument
        doc.Load(src)

        Dim posnrs As New List(Of String)
        Dim cparams As New List(Of String)

        Dim z1ppordcomps = doc.SelectNodes("//Z1PPORDCOMP[@SEGMENT='1']")
        For Each n As XmlNode In z1ppordcomps
            Dim posnr = n.SelectSingleNode("POSNR")
            Dim cparam = n.SelectSingleNode("CPARAM")
            If posnr IsNot Nothing AndAlso cparam IsNot Nothing Then
                posnrs.Add(posnr.InnerText)
                cparams.Add(cparam.InnerText)
            End If
        Next

        Console.WriteLine("POSNR: " & String.Join(",", posnrs))
        Console.WriteLine("CPARAM: " & String.Join(", ", cparams))

        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub

End Module
```

Outputs:

> POSNR: 0100,0200
>   CPARAM: RV ;, PLT;

You could access them individually with `posnrs(0)`, `posnrs(1)`, `cparams(0)`, and `cparams(1)`.

Answer (score 1):

Use XML Serialization

Create classes to represent your data

```vb
Imports System.Xml.Serialization
Imports System.IO
```

```vb
Public Class ZPPORDER01
    Public Property IDOC As IDOC
End Class
Public Class IDOC
    Public Property EDI_DC40 As EDI_DC40
    Public Property Z1PPORDITEM As Z1PPORDITEM
End Class

Public Class EDI_DC40
    Public Property TABNAM As String
    Public Property MANDT As String
    Public Property DOCNUM As String
End Class
Public Class Z1PPORDITEM
    <XmlAttribute>
    Public Property SEGMENT As Integer
    Public Property AUFNR As String
    Public Property POSNR As String
    Public Property Z1PPORDOPER As Z1PPORDOPER
End Class
Public Class Z1PPORDOPER
    <XmlAttribute>
    Public Property SEGMENT As Integer
    Public Property VORNR As String
    Public Property ARBPL As String
    <XmlElement("Z1PPORDCOMP")>
    Public Property Z1PPORDCOMPs As List(Of Z1PPORDCOMP)
End Class
Public Class Z1PPORDCOMP
    <XmlAttribute>
    Public Property SEGMENT As Integer
    Public Property POSNR As String
    Public Property CPARAM As String
End Class
```

Then deserialize

```vb
Dim s As New XmlSerializer(GetType(ZPPORDER01))
Dim z As ZPPORDER01
Using sr As New StreamReader("filename.xml")
    z = DirectCast(s.Deserialize(sr), ZPPORDER01)
End Using
For Each comp In z.IDOC.Z1PPORDITEM.Z1PPORDOPER.Z1PPORDCOMPs
    MessageBox.Show($"POSNR: {comp.POSNR}, CPARAM: {comp.CPARAM}")
Next
```